# How to compare values of two vectors

Tags: c++

Is anybody there who has a code on how to compare values of two arrays ?

I have two vectors and I am looking for the biggest and equal value of the both list.

Here is the code:

```
void fractionInLowestTerm(int fNumerator, int fDenominator)
{

    //let's get the dividers of fNumerator and fDenominator

    std::vector<int> dividerOfNumerator;
    std::vector<int> dividerOfDenominator;

    for (int i = 1; i <= fNumerator; i++) {

        if (fNumerator % i == 0) {
            dividerOfNumerator.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    for (int j = 1; fDenominator <= j; j++) {
        if (fDenominator % j == 0) {
            dividerOfDenominator.push_back(j);
        }
    }

    // let's get the greatest common divider of a and b;
    int pgcd = 1;

    // I do not know how to compare the values of dividers to get the greatest common value on a and b there is the code I started writing to get that
    for (int m = 0; m <= dividerOfNumerator.size() && m <= dividerOfDenominator.size(); m++) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the attempt you have made at writing the code. Also show desired input and output examples.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you elaborate on what you mean by "the biggest and equal value of the both list."?

Comment: What do you mean by *biggest and equal value of the both list*?

Comment: ***is anybody there who has a code on how to compare values of two arrays*** Yes of course but we are not supposed to give you code unless you show your attempt to solve the problem. The rules are here: [https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: You should stop telling that I have to put the code. I read how to post question and it is said that <<Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some>>.

Comment: By asking for the code we are trying to help. Many questions that don't include the code get closed without any help at all.  In the link I provided says this: ***Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. If we can't see enough work on your part your question will likely be booed off the stage; it will be voted down and closed.*** Your original question showed no effort on your part.

Comment: Oh excuse my mistake then. 
Thank you all

Comment: If one of the provided answers solves your question, then you should accept it. You can also post your own answer if you solved it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to compare the elements in two arrays for each index and save the greater one into a third array. In this case, just use your favourite max function for each index. For example:

```
void compare(int* array1, int* array2, int* array3, int size)
{
    for (int member = 0; member < size; ++member) {
        array3[member] = std::max(array1[member], array2[member]);
    }
}
```

or if you want to compare lists and write into third array that which array has bigger value in that index you can use following code

```
void compare(int* array1, int* array2, int* array3, int size)
{
    for (int member = 0; member < size; ++member) {
        if (array1[member] > array2[member]) {
            array3[member] = 1;
        }
        else if (array1[member] < array2[member]) {
            array3[member] = 2;
        }
        else if (array1[member] == array2[member]) {
            array3[member] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `vector`s containing the divisors are already sorted, you can use the `std::set_intersection` algorithm like this:

```
std::vector<int> commonDivisors;

std::set_intersection(dividerOfNumerator.begin(), dividerOfNumerator.end(),
                      dividerOfDenominator.begin(), dividerOfDenominator.end(),
                      std::back_inserter(commonDivisors));

int pgcd = commonDivisors.back();  // guaranteed to be non-empty since 1 is always a divisor
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nb6snE).

Answer (score 0):

Hello as you can see on the function name I wanted to write a function which put a function on the lowest term. I wanted to go through the gcd but I saw that it would consumes too much memory so here is what I've done. If it can help any member of the forum.

```
    void fractionInLowestTerm(int fNumerator, int fDenominator){
    
    //let's get on the divider of the number
    for (int i = 1; i < fNumerator and  i <fDenominator; i++) {
        
        if (fNumerator%i == 0 and fDenominator%i == 0) {
            fNumerator /= i;
            fDenominator /= i;
            i = 1;
        }
    }
    
    
}
```